# Test to see if toggle class is added after a button click - Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to test to see if a collapsible will collapse when clicked.

here is my JavaScript:

```
 $('#collapseOne').click(function () {
        $('#CollapsibleOne').collapse('toggle');
    });
```

and my test so far, the problem im facing is that it doesn't appear to click the button when  `button.click();` is called and my final except is returning false instead of true.

```
beforeAll(() => {
        let fs = require("fs");
        let fileContents = fs.readFileSync("templates/menu.html", "utf-8");
        document.open();
        document.write(fileContents);
        document.close();
    });

    test("expect element by id collapseOne to exist and collapse once clicked",
     () => {
        const element = document.getElementById("CollapsibleOne");
        const button = document.getElementById("collapseOne");
        expect(element).not.toBeNull();

        const hasToggleUnclicked = element.classList.contains('toggle');
        expect(hasToggleUnclicked).toBe(false);
        button.click();

        const hasToggleClicked = element.classList.contains('toggle');
        expect(hasToggleClicked).toBe(true);

    });
```

Comment: Hi! What exactly is the Jest error message? Please update your question. Does using `$(button).click()` instead in your unit test work?